# Notation of mutual information for continuous variable

Tags: probability-distributions, notation, entropy, mutual-information

I'm reading a paper, 'Mutual Information Neural Estimator.'
In this paper, the notation of mutual information is written as,
$$ I(X;Z) = \int_{\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Z}} \log \frac{d \mathbb{P}_{XZ}}{d \mathbb{P}_{X} \otimes d \mathbb{P}_{Z}} d \mathbb{P}_{XZ}.$$
Similarly, the KL divergence is written as ,
$$D_{KL} (\mathbb{P} \vert \vert \mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{E}_\mathbb{P} \Bigl[ \log \frac{d \mathbb{P}}{d \mathbb{Q}} \Bigr].$$

But I'm familiar with other notations like(from Wikipedia)
MI for continuous variable,
$$ I(X;Z) = \int_\mathcal{z} \int_\mathcal{x} P_{(X,Z)} (x,z) \log \Big( \frac{P_{(X,Y)}(x,y)}{P_X (x) P_Y (y)} \Bigr) dx dy, $$
and KL divergence
$$D_{KL} (P \vert \vert Q) = \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} P(x) \log \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}.$$

My questions are,

1. why they use $\text{\mathbb}$ format like $\mathbb{P}_X $ instead of $P(x)$?
2. And why is it $d \mathbb{P}_X $, not just $\mathbb{P}_X $?
3. Why $\sum P(x) $ become expectation?

I think the notation in this paper is quite confusing. Is there any reason they use this types of notation?

Comment: In the discrete case, $D_{KL}$ was in its pmf form. A natural way to write it for continuous variables is to use density. While $P_x$ is normally used to denote the pushforward measure on $X$, $dP_X$ could serve as its density, and sums become integrals. As for question 1, IDK.

Comment: The double-stroked $\mathbb P$ is common in probability theory (I would use, say $\mu$, $\nu$ in this context, to stress that we consider various measures, not the canonical $\mathbb P$ commonly used for the underlying probability space).

I find it instructive to move away from the discrete case. Notice that in your definition of the KL divergence (=relative entropy), the argument of the $\log$ is exactly the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $P$ to $Q$, commonly denoted by $\mathrm d P/\mathrm d Q$ or $\partial P/\partial Q$. The sum is just the expectation, so the definitions coincide.

Comment: Moreover, the definition on the top extends to *any* measures (defined on the same space), if $P$ is absolutely continuous to $Q$. Otherwise, there's also a reasonable value for the relative entropy, namely $\infty$. As for the mutual information, we always, in any case, have $I(X,y)=D((X,Y)\| X\otimes Y)$, where $X\otimes Y$ means that we take the product measure of the marginals (given by $X$ and $Y$). This means that the mutual information is just a very special type of relative entropy.